# Functional Pattern to check Connect 4 board for winner

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I want to learn some functional style programming, so I want to write a littel Connect 4 engine.

Given a board I want to determine if a player has won in that board state, so I need a function

```
let winner (board : Board) : Player option = ???
```

'Usually' one could simply loop through the rows, the columns, and the diagonals, and as soon as we find a winner we return whoever we found and 'break out'. I'm not sure if something like that is even possible in F#. 
In my current implementation I am using a helper function which takes a list of board cells and checks if there are four consecutive cells belonging to PlayerA or PlayerB. It returns a Player option type. 
Then in my main 'winner' function I check if there is a winner in the rows, if yes, return that Player, if None, check the columns, etc.
So basically I am doing a lot of matching and stuff, and it seems to me like this should be easier to do with some kind of bind, but I wouldn't know how.

So how would one approach this problem in functional style?

EDIT: Some Code Snippets
These are my basic types

```
type Player =
    | PlayerA
    | PlayerB

type Cell = 
    | Empty
    | Occupied of Player

type Board = Cell [] list 
    // Cell [] [] would probably be better, but some things were easier when I could use pattern matching x :: xs for lists
```

Here are some helper functions. This already seems like too much.

```
let rec getFours (l: 'a list):'a list list =
    if List.length l < 4 then
        [[]]
    elif List.length l = 4 then
        [l]
    else
        match l with
        | [] -> [[]]
        | x::xs -> [[x;l.[1];l.[2];l.[3]]] @ getFours xs

let quadToPlayer quad=
    if List.forall (fun x -> x = Occupied PlayerA) quad then
        Some PlayerA
    elif List.forall (fun x -> x = Occupied PlayerB) quad then
        Some PlayerB
    else
        None

let rowWinnerHelper (row : Cell []) : Player option=
    if Array.length row <4 then
        None
    else
        let possibleWinners = getFours (List.ofArray row) |> List.map quadToPlayer
        if List.exists (fun x -> x = Some PlayerA) possibleWinners then
           Some PlayerA
        elif List.exists (fun x -> x = Some PlayerB) possibleWinners then
           Some PlayerB
        else
           None 

let rowWinner (board:Board) : Player option = 
    let rowWinners = List.map rowWinnerHelper board
    if List.exists (fun x -> x = Some PlayerA) rowWinners then
        Some PlayerA
    elif List.exists (fun x -> x = Some PlayerB) rowWinners then
        Some PlayerB
    else
        None
```

What I don't like for example is that I am computing possible winners for all rows and all quadruples in each row etc. Instead of just stopping once I found the first winning Player.

Comment: can you share your code (partially) to suggest improvements

Answer (score 1):

Your could improve your getFours by computing if it's a win immediately rather than building lists.

```
let rec getFours player (l: 'a list): bool =
    if List.length l < 4 then
        false
    elif List.length l = 4 then
        quadToPlayer player l
    else
        match l with
        | [] -> false
        | x::xs -> (quadToPlayer player [x; l.[1];l.[2];l.[3]]) || (getFours xs)

let quadToPlayer player quad =
    List.forall (fun x -> x = Occupied player) quad
```

Alternatively, if you have a fixed board size you can then precompute winning patterns and you can bitmask against them.  This will increase significantly the performance.

Encode each players moves into a bit array (each) maybe using long type depending on the size of your board.  The example below is for tic-tac-toe.

```
       let white,black = board

       let winningPatterns = 
            [
                    0b111000000;  // horizontal
                    0b000111000;
                    0b000000111;
                    0b100100100;  // vertical
                    0b010010010;
                    0b001001001;

                    0b100010001;  // diagonal
                    0b001010100  ]

            let whiteWin = winningPatterns
                           |> Seq.map( fun p -> white &&& p = p )
                           |> Seq.reduce (||)

            let blackWin = winningPatterns
                           |> Seq.map( fun p -> black &&& p = p )
                           |> Seq.reduce (||)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an Elm implementation of Connect 4 [here](https://github.com/bradurani/connect-four-elm).
Following ideas from there, I learned that fold does the trick, as it can just keep track how many consecutive pieces by one player we have seen.

```
let arrayWinner (row:Cell []) (player:Player) =
    Array.fold (fun count p->
        if count = 4 then
            4
        elif p = Occupied player then
            count + 1
        else
            0
        ) 0 row 
    |> (=) 4
```

This can then be used in an 'exists'-check

```
let arrayOfArrayWinner (board:Cell [] []) (player:Player) =
    Array.exists (fun arr -> arrayWinner arr player) board
```

This bit of code accomplishes basically the same as the code snippet in the question.